# Bash: Generate md5 hash of string with special characters

Tags: bash, shell, hash, character, space

i would like to create a bash script that creates the md5-hash of a string.
BUT the string can contain special characters and spaces. How can i get it that such a string is readable for eg. md5sum?

I have written the following script as "md5.sh":

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n $1 | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'
```

But if i use "./md5.sh " (with a space at the end) this will not be recognized.
Also quoted cannot be read from the script. And a single " will end in an prompt...

Hope someone can help me :)

Comment: `a single " will end in an prompt` - You have to quote arguments to the script, so if you do `./md5.sh '"'` (that's a double quote inside two single quotes) you will get the correct response. Same goes for any strings containing spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to quote the parameter in the script (and use `printf`; the world would be a better place if people forgot `echo` existed):

```
printf '%s' "$1" | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'
```

Second, to pass an actual space as the argument, it must be quoted as well so that the shell doesn't discard it:

```
./md5.sh " "
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for spaces, but how about other special characters? Eg. for single or double will work: `./md5.sh '"'` or `./md5.sh "'"`. But what if the string contains both single and double quotes?

Comment: If it contains both types of quotes, you need to escape them with a backslash. `"'\""` is a string consisting of a single quote and a double quote. Note that you cannot include even an escaped single quote inside single quotes (`'\''` is not a valid string, or rather, it is a quoted backslash followed by an unclosed single quote), although `bash` provides yet another form of quoting that does allow escaped single quotes: `$'\''`.